# How to get latest filename from a folder using PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How to get the latest filename from a folder using pace automation framework

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom tag :

#Tag=getLastModifiedFile, Att1=path, Att2=keyName

getLastModifiedFile=com.tr.execution.activities.GetLastModifiedFile

```
          <getLastModifiedFile path="./sample_xml" keyName="file"></getLastModifiedFile>

          <variable keyName="file_name" expression="'${file}'.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')" ></variable>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).